# Google+ Badge on Blogger - very hit and miss (Artisteer template)

Tags: blogger

http://jmopes.blogspot.com

The sidebar is a bit of a mess, but hopefully you either see 'Google+ Badge' heading and empty space, or the above with said badge displaying. I've tried various methods, adding as a gadget, using the generator on google+ etc. but the best I have achieved is it sometimes showing! I'm not sure where I am going wrong as it works perfectly in the gadget preview...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the answers guys. For anyone using Artisteer who runs into widget problems, this is the solution I found:

Go to template and search for if (widgetContent.indexOf('bravenet.com/counter/code.php') > -1) return true;' - you'll see a list of addresses - this is the url's artisteer chooses to get external javascript in widgets - if you copy and paste what you just searched for, and replace the url with 'website.com/javascript' (e.g. google+ widgets would be https://plus.google.com) : the result is fully working javascript widgets!

Answer (score 0):

Google+Badge codes are required to put in a gadget with reference to below steps.

1. Go to Blogger dashboard > Layout
2. Open the gadget where you have placed HTML codes of Google+Badge.
3. Select entire codes and replace with below HTML codes.

   ```
   <!-- Place this tag after the last widget tag. -->
   <script type="text/javascript">
     (function() {
       var po = document.createElement('script'); po.type = 'text/javascript'; po.async = true;
       po.src = 'https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js';
       var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(po, s);
     })();
   </script>
   ```
4. Click on save and View the blog for result.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It still doesn't fix it though, but interestingly enough, I tried the 'add a gadget' route with a dummy blog - and it works perfectly! So it must be down to the template I'm using, as I used Artisteer to create it rather than use a dynamic theme.

Answer (score 0):

You could go to https://developers.google.com/+/web/badge/ and create a badge that fits your sidebar(you can set the width of the badge there).

Thank you